# Are they the same? 1. I didn't borrow the book until today. 2. Until today, I borrowed the book

Tags: grammar

Are they the same?

1. I didn't borrow the book until today.
2. Until today, I borrowed the book.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a duplicate, but you might find this similar question interesting: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/325340/he-didn-t-get-married-until-he-was-well-into-his-forties-whats-the-implicatio

Comment: Example 1 is possible. Example 2 is meaningless.

Comment: 2 is certainly unusual, although "Until today, I borrowed the book often" or "Until today, I borrowed the book once a year" are fine. Also "I borrowed the book until today" means "I borrowed the book in the past and returned it today". I think "until" works differently with negative phrases and positive phrases, as well as other factors.

Comment: I would say that they mean the opposite. **I didn't borrow the book until today.** means "I didn't borrow the book in the past, but I have done so today", whilst **Until today, I borrowed the book.** means "I borrowed the book some time in the past but I have returned it today - it's no longer borrowed"

Answer (score 0):

Nope. But I wonder what actually the question is. If you had been borrowing the book in the past until today it is not the same as not borrowing it.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same

> I didn't borrow the book until today.

means that I had not borrowed the book before this day, when you did.

> Until today, I borrowed the book.

mean that I borrowed the book, and then I returned it -- or bought it, or something else that meant it ceased to be borrowed.